# The variable belongs to a range of values

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have this code:

```
If t=241 Then 

...

End if
```

But if i want the variable to be equal to the range of values ​​(241-540), how to write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your condition start to become more complicated, you might want to take a look at the [Select Case statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement):

```
Select Case t
Case 241 To 540, 620 To 728 
    'Code executed for values to t between 241 and 540, or between 620 and 728
    'similar to If (t >= 241 And t <= 540) Or (t >=620 And t <= 728) Then
Case 800
    'Code executed if t=800
Case Else
    'Other case
End Select
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're looking for:

```
If t > 241 And t < 540 Then

'...

End if
```

Comment: if the limits need to be included, you need to use `>=` and `<=`.